# How to distinguish mouse events from touchscreen events?

Tags: java, android, input, mouse, touchscreen

In my application I need to know which input device produced touch event: mouse, touchscreen, touchpad or something else.

event.getSource() returns:

```
for mouse: 8194
for touchscreen: 4098
```

I've made a method which outputs to logcat types of source:

```
void dumpSource(MotionEvent e) {
    int s = e.getSource();
    Log.e("LorieService", "Motion event is from sources: " +
            ((s&InputDevice.SOURCE_KEYBOARD)!=0?"keyboard ":"") +
            ((s&InputDevice.SOURCE_DPAD)!=0?"dpad ":"") +
            ((s&InputDevice.SOURCE_GAMEPAD)!=0?"gamepad ":"") +
            ((s&InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN)!=0?"touchscreen ":"") +
            ((s&InputDevice.SOURCE_MOUSE)!=0?"mouse ":"") +
            ((s&InputDevice.SOURCE_STYLUS)!=0?"stylus ":"") +
            ((s&InputDevice.SOURCE_BLUETOOTH_STYLUS)!=0?"bt_stylus ":"") +
            ((s&InputDevice.SOURCE_TRACKBALL)!=0?"trackball ":"") +
            ((s&InputDevice.SOURCE_MOUSE_RELATIVE)!=0?"mouse_relative ":"") +
            ((s&InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCHPAD)!=0?"touchpad ":"") +
            ((s&InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCH_NAVIGATION)!=0?"touch_navigation ":"") +
            ((s&InputDevice.SOURCE_ROTARY_ENCODER)!=0?"rotary_encoder ":"") +
            ((s&InputDevice.SOURCE_JOYSTICK)!=0?"joystick ":"") +
            ((s&InputDevice.SOURCE_HDMI)!=0?"hdmi":"")

    );
}
```

But it outputs `touchscreen mouse stylus bt_stylus` for both mouse and touchscreen.

How to distinguish mouse and touchscreen events in proper way?

Comment: There is method View.isInTouchMode() and it is an answer for distinguishing between mouse and touchscreen, but not gamepad. It behaves correct if you are changing from mouse to touch, but if you use touch and then move mouse then cursor appears but view is still in touch mode. I can treat ACTION_HOVER_MOVE as mouse only and it will not disturb me.

Comment: But there is still problem with gamepad and stylus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't how to check it.  The correct way to check it would be `type = s&InputDevice.SOURCE_MASK;` then check equality matching on type.  The way you're doing it will return true if any of the bits of the source are the same for the two device types.  The type itself is not a bitmask, its an integer enumeration.

Comment: OK. Found it in SDK sources. InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN = 4098 and InputDevice.SOURCE_MOUSE = 8194 as in my example.

Comment: @TwaikYont You can just check if  type == InputDevices.SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN, no need to look up the values.  In fact its less readable if you do.

Comment: Like that? switch(e.getSource()) {
case InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN: return onTouchscreen(v, event);
case InputDevice.SOURCE_MOUSE: return onMouse(v, event);
case InputDevice.SOURCE_GAMEPAD: return onGamepad(v, event);
}

Comment: You need to use my code to get the type. Then switch on the type

Comment: `boolean isMouse = (e.getSource()&InputDevice.SOURCE_MOUSE) == InputDevice.SOURCE_MOUSE` ?